# Wrapping methods using db connection in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, dbcontext

I was following the [MVC music store tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-5) and I came to the part where they are using database connections (`DbConnection` is a child of `DbContext`). I was taught to create methods like this (wrapping with using):

```
public class StoreManagerController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /StoreManager/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        using(var db = new DbConnection())
        {
            var albums = db.Albums.Include(a => a.Genre).Include(a => a.Artist);
            return View(albums.ToList());
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

but Visual Studio generated me a controller which looked like this:

```
public class StoreManagerController : Controller
{
    private DbConnection db = new DbConnection();

    //
    // GET: /StoreManager/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var albums = db.Albums.Include(a => a.Genre).Include(a => a.Artist);
        return View(albums.ToList());
    }

    ...
}
```

I assume, Visual Studio isn't wrong, but why was I told to wrap each method with `using` to make the connections as short as possible and also the users to use separate connections?

Answer (score 2):

*I assume, Visual Studio isn't wrong, but why was I told to wrap each method with using*

```
    using(var db = new DbConnection())
    {
        var albums = db.Albums.Include(a => a.Genre).Include(a => a.Artist);
        return View(albums.ToList());
    }
```

The scope of `db` remains only within the curly braces. This is perhaps another purpose that `using` keyword serves in `C#`. It defines the scope of a variable, here in the above case it is your `db` object.

Now, if you debug the code that visual studio generated for you, then you notice that there is a `Dispose method` being invoked each and every time an object of a controller class is made or in other words, an action method is called within the corresponding Controller.

The DBContext instance is always disposed because of the following -

- As you load more objects and their references into memory, the memory consumption of the context may increase rapidly. This may cause performance issues.
- If an exception causes the context to be in an unrecoverable state, the whole application may terminate.
- The chances of running into concurrency-related issues increase as the gap between the time when the data is queried and updated grows.

*For more info - [Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/data/jj729737.aspx)*

Answer (score 1):

This might depend on the usability of your app; whether or not you need a persistent connection, and the cost of creating one (and a myriad of other factors).

But for starters, you should always dispose of the connection (as in the first pattern, **not** the one suggested by Visual Studio) and then move to other patterns based on new requirements or performance-related issues.

The biggest issue I see with the Visual Studio-suggested options is that you have no way of controlling the lifetime of the `DbConncetion` object, and are leaving it up to the garbage collector to eventually dispose of it. This could leave the connection resources in use for an rather undetermined period of time.

Comment: Their example might be providing an override on Controller.Disposing(true) that disposes the context. That is what the T4 templates do in MVC5.

Comment: If that's the case, then the behavior might be similar. However, I still prefer the readability of using the `using` statement, rather than relying on a slightly less obvious method override. But that's just me...

Comment: If you have a private method that needs access to the context then you would need to have that method take the context as a parameter, or just make it available to the class. I never use the context directly in my controllers, though.

Comment: Well, yes. The answer is based in the current example. In an actual production-like design, these types of operation that use the `DbConnection` directly should be isolated into a layer of itself with a `IDao` or `IRepository` interface available to the controller.